# Why is git pull showing new branches all the time?

Tags: git

I'm using git bash for Windows:

```
$ git version
git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0
```

Everything has been working fine for months, I've been gradually getting used to how git works, then all of a sudden, git pull is retrieving a number of "new" branches each time I try to pull:

```
me@MYPC /d/Projects/MyProject (master)
$ git pull
From github.com:ClientUsername/RepoName
 * [new branch]      branch1 -> origin/branch1
 * [new branch]      branch2 -> origin/branch2
Already up-to-date.

me@MYPC /d/Projects/MyProject (master)
$ git pull
From github.com:ClientUsername/RepoName
 * [new branch]      branch1 -> origin/branch1
 * [new branch]      branch2 -> origin/branch2
Already up-to-date.
```

Have I configured something incorrectly? Is this normal behavior?

---

**EDIT**

After some helpful comments, I deleted the branch files from .git\refs\remotes\origin. I tried to pull again and got the following:

```
me@MyPC /d/Projects/MyProject (master)
$ git pull
From github.com:ClientUsername/RepoName
 * [new branch]      Branch1 -> origin/Branch1
 * [new branch]      Branch2 -> origin/Branch2
 * [new branch]      branch1 -> origin/branch1
 * [new branch]      branch2 -> origin/branch2
Already up-to-date.
me@MyPC /d/Projects/MyProject (master)
$ git pull
From github.com:ClientUsername/RepoName
 * [new branch]      Branch1 -> origin/Branch1
 * [new branch]      Branch2 -> origin/Branch2
Already up-to-date.
```

The only difference being the case of the branch names?

Comment: strange indeed. After the pull are those branches listed? Are they present under .git/refs/remotes/origin?

Comment: Yep, they're there... git branch -a, right?

Comment: `git branch -r`. I'd delete .git/refs/remotes/origin/branch1 and 2 as first attempt

Comment: Deleted - and this result is even more curious... I will update the question.

Comment: seem like you're hit by case insensitive filenames issue? or special characters in branch name

Comment: one more idea: look in .git/packed_refs and if the entry present for your branches delete those too

Comment: There are hyphens in the branch name - and uppercase / lower case alpha / numeric characters. We use the same naming convention for all repos. I also just tried to delete files from .git\logs\refs\remotes\origin too, but I'm still getting the same result :(

Comment: Nope, nothing in there :(

Comment: @BalogPal your comments fixed it for me :) I removed the "faulty" branches from both .git/refs/remotes/origin/ and .git/packed_refs Was the same case difference problem, thanks!

Comment: Same issue here on osx, one branch was pushed to repository and later merged with master but every time I run git pull on master it keeps saying `Already up-to-date` but also says `[new branch]   branchname -> origin/branchname`

Answer (score 42):

In my case, the issue was related to two branches having the same name (one uppercase, one lower case). Once I removed the "duplicate" branch from remote origin, I ran the following:

```
git fetch --prune origin
```

and the [new branch] message stop showing after every pull. For documentation on [prune](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---prune) see reference.

Comment: thank you, this has been an annoyance for quite a while and this resolved it.

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm. Per documentation --prune: "Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote." not only it removed remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote but also fixed uppercase lowercase name mismatch.

Answer (score 14):

Had a similar issue, problem was with an existing local folder not matching the name in the remote server due to case-sensitive differences.
What worked for me was going to

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin
```

where you can find the affected branch folder name and either rename it to the name suggested in the `*[new branch]` line OR delete it and `pull` again, the `pull` will re-create the folder in the correct filesystem case.

Although from your last edit it looks like in the remote server you have both folders (ie `Branch1` and `branch1`) so I will double check which one is the correct folder and delete the remote wrong one, then make sure the folder name is matching the one in your local.

Answer (score 10):

I could reproduce the behavior by having a branch *not* listed in .git/packed_refs and renaming its file in .git/refs/remotes/origin to the same but different case.  (on NTFS filesystem).  And it is cured by renaming back.

Guess if you could rename to the form that matches the remote name, it would be a fix for you.

Thinking more, and using the first form after edit:

You must have two branches with similar name just differing in case on remote!

And the problem is because they want to create the same file. You must fix it on the remote, by renaming one of the similar-named branches.

Comment: Well, I've tried all your suggestions, but it's still happening. It's almost as if my local repo is set up to pull the same branch twice. I'm going to re-clone.

Comment: Cloning in another location has solved the problem. However, github is also listing both repos separately, but all the hashes are the same. I think we'll try renaming next... if that doesn't work, we need to speak to gihub I think!

Answer (score 10):

As you can see here:

```
* [new branch]      Branch1 -> origin/Branch1
* [new branch]      Branch2 -> origin/Branch2
* [new branch]      branch1 -> origin/branch1
* [new branch]      branch2 -> origin/branch2
```

You have 4 branches and pairs of them have the same name with different upper/lowercase. This can’t be mirrored on Windows since branches are stored as files and you can not have two files `Branch1` and `branch1` in the same folder.

To fix that, remove one of these, by running `git push origin :Branch1` and the same for `Branch2`.

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

```bash
for i in {1..10}; do git pack-refs --all; git pull; done
```

This caused a lot of head scratching for me despite most of the helpful pieces of information already being here.

### Case [in]sensitive File Systems

This seems to be a side affect of case insensitive file systems. When a remote repository file system is case sensitive and a local repository is not, then the local repository has trouble comparing local branches to to remote branches and considers them *new*.

#### Case Insensitive File System

```bash
mkdir bug && ls 
# => bug
mkdir Bug; ls
# => mkdir: Bug: File exists
# => bug
```

The filesystem believes that the directory "Bug" already exists because it is case insensitive and considered the existing "bug" directory to be the same as the "Bug" directory.

This comes into play with git because git will store [refs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References), or files that point to a specific commit, on your local hard drive and each `/` in a branch name results in the creation of a directory.

Lets take two branches as an example:

- `Bug/foo`
- `bug/bar`

In a repository that knows about these two branches you would expect to see the following files:

- `.git/refs/remotes/origin/Bug/foo`
- `.git/refs/remotes/origin/bug/bar`

If the file system won't allow two distinct subdirectories "Bug" and "bug" then git runs into a problem. git continues to keep the refs in sync with the remote branches when executing `git pull`, but it also outputs a warning that this is the first time that the local repository has seen this "new" branch.

### Solution

Execute `git pack-refs --all` followed by `git pull` and then repeat until all the warnings go away. This will convert any local refs stored as directories and files into a single flat file (`.git/packed-refs`).

The default is to pull down new branches as *unpacked*, or as directories and files. You will have to execute this any time you get a new branch that runs into a case mismatch.

### Demo

Here is a script that attempts to demonstrate the problem.

To truly replicate this you will need to create a case sensitive Volume (See code comments).

If you do not want to add or remove volumes, change the value of `REMOTE` to `REMOTE="${SCRIPT_DIR}/casing-remote"`. This is not going to perform exactly as expected because the "remote" repository in this case is just another directory on a case insensitive file system, so it is impossible to create two remote branches with a case mismatch. Whichever directory makes it to remote first ("Bug") will win.

To fully recreate the issue we need a remote repository that respects case sensitivity and a local repository that does not.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# WARNING
# These are dangerous commands that create and delete
# disk volumes. Uncomment and execute at your own risk.

# [BEGIN DANGEROUS COMMANDS]
# 
# This is the command to "cleanup" or remove the newly created Volume.
# This will delete the Volume with an id of `disk1s9` that is going to
# change depending on your drive setup. Execute `diskutil list` to see 
# general disk info
#
# `diskutil apfs deleteVolume disk1s9`
#
# Create a case sensitive volume
# `diskutil apfs addVolume disk1 APFSX Casesensitive` # disk1s9
#
# [END DANGEROUS COMMANDS]

SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &> /dev/null && pwd)
REMOTE=/Volumes/Casesensitive/casing
# Set REMOTE="${SCRIPT_DIR}/casing-remote"
# If you do not want to create a case sensitive volume
REPO="${SCRIPT_DIR}/casing-bob"
REPO_OTHER="${SCRIPT_DIR}/casing-alice"

rm -rf "${REPO}" "${REPO_OTHER}" "${REMOTE}" && \
  mkdir "${REPO}" "${REPO_OTHER}" "${REMOTE}" && \
  cd "${REMOTE}" && \
  git init --bare && \
  cd "${REPO}" && \
  git init && \
  echo "#casing" > README.md && \
  git add README.md && \
  git commit -m "init commit" && \
  git branch -M master && \
  git remote add origin "${REMOTE}" && \
  git push -u origin master && \
  git clone "${REMOTE}" "${REPO_OTHER}" && \
  cd "${REPO}" && \
  git checkout -b Bug/foo && \
  touch foo && \
  git add foo && \
  git commit -m "adding foo file" && \
  git push --set-upstream origin Bug/foo && \
  cd "${REPO_OTHER}" && \
  git checkout -b bug/bar && \
  touch bar && \
  git add bar && \
  git commit -m "added bar file" && \
  git push --set-upstream origin bug/bar && \
  cd "${REPO_OTHER}" && \

  # casing-alice always thinks that Bug/foo is a new branch
  # because it has a loacl ref of ".git/refs/remotes/origin/bug/bar"
  # so it doesn't know Bug/foo and bug/foo are the same branch.
  # It does seem that local "bug/foo" 
  # is in sync with remote "Bug/foo" despite the warning

  git pull
  git pull
```

The problem is apparent when listing remote branches in each repo (Bob and Alice) with `git branch -r`. The output changes depending on which casing was created first.

##### casing-bob (git branch -r)

```
origin/Bug/bar
origin/Bug/foo
origin/master
```

##### casing-alice (git branch -r)

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/bug/bar
origin/bug/foo
origin/master
```

##### remote (git branch)

```
Bug/foo
bug/bar
* master
```

Each repo has a different view of what the actual remote branches are.

I opened a bug with git. Here is the key information

> Yes, it is [a known gotcha].
> The thing is, that Git at the moment is unable to handle to branches
> like Foo and foo on case-insensitive file systems.
> Because branch names are stored as files, and that doesn't typially work
> well under Windows or MacOs.

> As a workaround,
> git pack-refs
> can be used.

[git bug thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20230320191210.jzzq5c2ssxcltvoc@tb-raspi4/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm also running git for Windows (version 2.20.0.windows.1), and had the same issue but managed to solve it with help from other answers in this thread.

In my case a new branch was added by a team member under a path that differed by case to already existing branches.

The following branches existed:

```
feature/branch-1
feature/branch-2
```

Then a new branch got created:

```
Feature/branch-3
```

Note all branches have unique names; but the case differs on the word `feature`.

Upon `git pull` I got a notification about a new branch; which created a `branch-3` file for the under `.git\refs\remotes\origin\feature`.  The order of branch creation probably matters here; because `.git\refs\remotes\origin\feature` existed prior to `.git\refs\remotes\origin\Feature`; my path was lowercase.  Reversing the order of branch creation would probably result in a capital `Feature` path.

Every subsequent `git pull` would report this new branch.

The problem was that even though the file for the branch existed; the branch was not added to `.git\packed-refs`.  The fix was to manually add a line for the problem branch **with correct casing**:

```
# pack-refs with: peeled fully-peeled sorted 
...
<hash> refs/remotes/origin/feature/branch-1
<hash> refs/remotes/origin/feature/branch-2
<hash> refs/remotes/origin/Feature/branch-3
...
```

Where the `<hash>` was taken from the `.git\refs\remotes\origin\feature\branch-3` file.

Also; speculating on the original question.  Let's just say I had the following branches:

```
feature/branch-1
feature/Branch-1
```

Windows would write the hash for both branches into the single path `.git\refs\remotes\origin\feature\branch-1` (or capital B depending on branch creation order).  I don't know what the implications of that are if you tried to `git checkout` both branches.

I am also betting that there's only a single entry in `.git\packed-refs` for both the branches.  Perhaps adding entries for both branches would help to get rid of the new branch message reported by `git pull` but as mentioned above, `git checkout feature/branch-1` followed by `git checkout feature/Branch-1` might be interesting.

Hope this is useful to someone else!

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me and able to resolve it.
Every branch we created in the repo will be added to the path `.git/refs/remotes/origin`
There is another fie `.git/packed-refs` which maintains the hash value for each branch.

Here comes the problem, file system will not accept case sensitive folder/file names. So, you will have

1. Either `.git/refs/remotes/origin/Feature` or `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature`
2. Either `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/SampleBranchName` or `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/samplebranchname`

In this scenario, the respective hash value will not be mentioned in the `.git/packed-refs` file.

So, if you add the hash value of the branch which is in the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/SampleBranchName` to the list of `.git/packed-refs`, problem will be solved

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me! Thank you so much. In my case, I had:
- `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature` but no `.git/refs/remotes/origin/Feature`
- `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature` in `.git/packed-refs` but not `.git/refs/remotes/origin/Feature`.

I solved it by doing:
`hash=$(git rev-parse origin/Feature) &&
echo "$hash refs/remotes/origin/Feature" >> .git/packed-refs`. 
Then a `git pull` updated once more, and further `git pull`s don't show any changes. 

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to Paul, above. Unlike Paul, I run git locally on Cygwin on Windows. The git remote is a Linux server.)

I kept getting this error with git advising about 'someBranchName' every time I did a git pull:

```
$ git pull
From <server>:<path>
 * [new branch]        someBranchName -> origin/someBranchName
Already up to date
```

There were two branches with differences in case:

```
$ git branch -a | grep -i SomeBranchName
  remotes/origin/someBranchName
  remotes/origin/SomeBranchName
```

What worked for me was to edit `.git/refs/remotes/origin/someBranchName` (this file existed in my local repo) and get its hash. Then edit `.git/packed-refs` and add a second entry with the same hash for both branches:

```
012345ae refs/remotes/origin/someBranchName
012345ae refs/remotes/origin/SomeBranchName
```

Comment: Glad I could help!  For anyone reading in future - I am on Windows (I think the commonality between @happyblue and me is that the NTFS filesystem is not case sensitive for resolving file names) but using [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) - and I primarily use git bash.  The remote is Azure DevOps so I can't really speculate on the remote OS.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is simply:

```
rm .git/index
git reset
```

Comment: Would have to explain what you're doing here and whether there are side effects